# Docker containers affecting others in compose environment in unclear ways

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose

When I run the following docker-compose, I get the output below, and the build succeeds.

`docker-compose.prod.yaml`

```yaml
version: '3.7'

services:
  flask_base:
    build:
      context: ./flask
      dockerfile: flask.base.dockerfile

  flask:
    build:
      context: ./flask
      dockerfile: flask.prod.dockerfile
    environment:
      - FLASK_ENV=production
    volumes:
      - './flask:/flask'
    depends_on:
      - redis
      - flask_base

  redis:
    image: redis

  front_end_build:
    build:
      context: ./front_end
      dockerfile: front_end.build.dockerfile

  nginx:
    build:
      context: ./nginx
      dockerfile: nginx.prod.dockerfile
    ports:
      - 80:80 # serves front end
      - 5000:5000 # serves flask
    environment:
      - CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    depends_on:
      - flask
      - front_end_build
```

Output:

```
Successfully built fafba03381e4
Successfully tagged ivd_nginx:latest
Recreating ivd_front_end_build_1 ... done
Creating ivd_flask_base_1        ... done
Creating ivd_redis_1             ... done
Creating ivd_flask_1             ... done
Recreating ivd_nginx_1           ... done
Attaching to ivd_nginx_1
```

When I add the following to the top, it fails, but the failure doesn't appear to have anything to do with the new services:

New content, at the top of the file:

```yaml
  message_router_base:
    build:
      context: ./message_router
      dockerfile: message_router.base.dockerfile

  message_router:
    build:
      context: message_router
      dockerfile: message_router.prod.dockerfile
    volumes:
      - './message_router:/message_router'
    ports:
      - 8701:8701
    depends_on:
      - message_router_base

  # and add message_router to flask:depends_on
```

Output:

```
Successfully built fafba03381e4
Successfully tagged ivd_nginx:latest
Starting ivd_front_end_build_1     ... error
Creating ivd_message_router_base_1 ... 
Creating ivd_redis_1               ... 
Creating ivd_message_router_base_1 ... done
Creating ivd_redis_1               ... done
Creating ivd_flask_base_1          ... done
Creating ivd_message_router_1      ... done
Creating ivd_flask_1               ... done

ERROR: for front_end_build  Cannot start service front_end_build: network dd51af742491a5a3bfa3ef1859a7c6a29aee2c564b4baae83dcab58026076cb2 not found
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

The second time, it's trying to *start* `front_end_build`, which doesn't need to be started (and can't be!). Why does adding the containers, which aren't touched by `front_end_build` (except that nginx depends on front_end_build and nginx also depends on flask which depends on message router) cause a different behavior?

---

I'm spinning up the containers with the command:
`docker-compose down && docker-compose -f docker-compose.prod.yml up --build --remove-orphans nginx`

Here's all the dockerfiles.

I have the base/prod files separated because I also have dev dockerfiles that simply run a different ending command (e.g., `message_router.dev.dockerfile` runs the auto-reloading `watcher.py`). I wanted to avoid duplicating the contents of the base DF and having to change both when anything changes.

`message_router.base.dockerfile`

```
FROM python:3.8.0-alpine as ivd-message-router-base
RUN apk add gcc libc-dev linux-headers
COPY apk_packages.txt /message_router/apk_packages.txt
WORKDIR /message_router
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN set -e; \
    cat apk_packages.txt | xargs apk add --no-cache --virtual .build-deps; \
    pip3 install -r requirements.txt; \
    apk del .build-deps;
ENV REDIS_DOCKER_NAME='redis'
ENV MESSAGE_ROUTER_DOCKER_NAME='message_router'
ENV REDIS_PORT=6379
ENV WEBSOCKET_PORT=8701
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=TRUE
```

`message_router.prod.dockerfile`

```
FROM ivd-message-router-base
CMD python message_router.py
```

`flask.base.dockerfile`

```
FROM python:3.8.0-alpine as ivd-flask-base
COPY ./requirements.txt /flask/requirements.txt
COPY ./apk_packages.txt /flask/apk_packages.txt
WORKDIR /flask
RUN set -e; \
    cat apk_packages.txt | xargs apk add --no-cache --virtual .build-deps; \
    pip3 install -r requirements.txt; \
    apk del .build-deps;
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=TRUE
ENV FLASK_RUN_HOST=0.0.0.0
```

`flask.prod.dockerfile`

```
FROM ivd-flask-base
CMD uwsgi --ini flask_app.ini
```

`front_end.build.dockerfile`

```
FROM node:13.12.0-alpine as front-end-build
WORKDIR /srv
COPY package.json ./
COPY yarn.lock ./
RUN yarn install --frozen-lockfile
COPY . /srv
RUN yarn build
```

`nginx.prod.dockerfile`

```
FROM nginx
EXPOSE 80
COPY --from=front-end-build /srv/build /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY ./nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d
```

Answer (score 0):

Every service you list in `docker-compose.yml` will be started every time you run `docker-compose up`.  There's no notion of "a service that shouldn't be started".

As such, this split of "base" containers, which just have a Dockerfile, and "runtime" containers, that actually run the thing, doesn't really make sense.  The reverse part of this is that an image without a default `CMD` is just a collection of files, and isn't really useful on its own; if you have a non-default configuration that needs a different command, you can override that in the `docker-compose.yml`.

I'd rewrite this with a `flask/Dockerfile`:

```sh
FROM python:3.8.0-alpine
WORKDIR /flask
COPY requirements.txt api_packages.txt ./
...
COPY . ./
CMD uwsgi --ini flask_app.ini
```

Note that (a) this image contains the code it needs to run (the Docker image does not depend on content outside of Docker), and (b) there is a default `CMD`.  Then your `docker-compose.yml` can have

```yaml
version: '3.7'
services:
  # no "flask_base"
  flask:
    build: ./flask  # with the default Dockerfile name
    environment:
      - FLASK_ENV=production
    # do not overwrite the image code with volumes:
    depends_on:
      - redis
  et: cetera
```

If you do need to run this in "development mode", and you can't use a native setup like a Python virtual environment, you can replace the image's code with what's running on the host and replace its default command with something else.  You can use an [override file](https://docs.docker.com/compose/extends/#multiple-compose-files) for this or otherwise provide a separate Docker Compose YAML specification.  So for example `docker-compose.override.yml` could have:

```yaml
version: '3.7'
services:
  flask:
    # Keeps build:, depends_on: from base file
    volumes:
      - ./flask:/flask
    command: python manage.py runserver --host 0.0.0.0:8080
```

This won't necessarily solve the strange Docker network error, but it does avoid having containers declared in the `docker-compose.yml` file that can't be started, but since they aren't running, `docker-compose up` will restart them every time.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about that command override in the docker-compose file. That's a pretty cool trick, I now have a single dockerfile for each module and differentiate how they run using the compose file. Combining the nginx and front end dockerfiles seems to have fixed the network issue.